# Fastest way to recycle vector along matrix rows

Tags: r

I have a n x m matrix `mat` and a vector `vec` of length m. Is there a fast way to subtract this vector from each row of the matrix, recycling it as necessary.

Example:

```
mat = structure(c(3.01, 1.44, 3.31, 1.34, 3.79, 1.65, 3.06, 1.12, 2.34, 
0.27, 2.63, 0.63, 2.73, 0.94, 3.1, 1.34, 2.75, 0.75, 2.83, 0.58
), .Dim = c(2L, 10L))

vec = colMeans(mat)
```

Whats the fastest way to subtract `vec` from each row of `mat`?  `aperm` seems very inefficient.

```
aperm(aperm(mat) - vec)
```

Allocating a second matrix doesn't seem too spiffy either.

```
mat - matrix(vec, ncol=ncol(mat), nrow = nrow(mat), by.row =T)
```

Note: This question is a repost of a previous question closed as a duplicate. Unfortunately the duplicates lacked relevant, thorough answers so I decided to add it along with an answer.

Comment: Worth pointing out that if you were subtracting from columns instead of rows the recycling will work by default, `mat - rowMeans(mat)`. You could of course transpose and do this, `t(t(mat) - vec)`, but this will 2nd fastest of the solutions proposed below. If you can refactor your code to use columns instead of rows after the fact, `t(mat) - vec` is competitive for fastest. And if you can make upstream changes to avoid the transpose entirely it will certainly be fastest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(microbenchmark)

byrow.speed.benchmark = function(ncol, nrow) {
  mat = matrix(rnorm(nrow * ncol), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)
  vec = colSums(mat)


  microbenchmark(
    aperm(aperm(mat) - vec),
    t(t(mat) - vec),
    mat - matrix(vec, ncol=ncol(mat), nrow = nrow(mat), byrow =T),
    sweep(mat, 2, vec),
    mat - rep(vec, each = nrow(mat)),
    #mat %*% diag(vec),
    mat - vec[col(mat)],
    mat - vec,
    times = 300
  )
}


byrow.speed.benchmark(10, 10)
```

Comparing several methods of applying across matrix rows we find that allocating a vector is the fastest.

```
Unit: nanoseconds
                                                             expr   min    lq      mean median    uq   max neval
                                          aperm(aperm(mat) - vec)  8642  9283 10214.287   9923 10243 80344   300
                                                  t(t(mat) - vec)  6722  7362  7950.130   8002  8323 27208   300
 mat - matrix(vec, ncol = ncol(mat), nrow = nrow(mat), byrow = T)  3201  3841  4282.947   4161  4482 20486   300
                                               sweep(mat, 2, vec) 26888 28489 30016.310  29448 30089 85145   300
                                 mat - rep(vec, each = nrow(mat))  2560  3201  3481.630   3521  3841 10883   300
                                              mat - vec[col(mat)]  1600  2241  2594.970   2561  2881  6081   300
                                                        mat - vec     0   320   389.530    320   321  1921   300
```

How does this scale?

```
ncols = floor(10^((4:12)/4))
nrows = floor(10^((4:12)/4))

results = cbind(expand.grid(ncols, nrows), aperm = NA, t=NA, alloc = NA, sweep = NA, rep = NA,  indices=NA, control = NA)

for (i in seq(nrow(results))) {
  df = byrow.speed.benchmark(results[i,1], results[i,2])

  results[i,3:9] = sapply(split(df$time, as.numeric(df$expr)), mean)
}

library(ggplot2)

df = reshape2::melt(results, id.vars= c("Var1", "Var2"))

colnames(df) = c("ncol", "nrow", "method", "meantime")



ggplot(subset(df, ncol==1000)) + geom_point(aes(x = log10(ncol*nrow), y=meantime, colour = method))+ geom_line(aes(x = log10(ncol*nrow), y=meantime, colour = method))  + ggtitle("Scaling with cell number.") + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1E6))
ggplot(subset(df, ncol==1000)) + geom_point(aes(x = log10(ncol*nrow), y=meantime, colour = method))+ geom_line(aes(x = log10(ncol*nrow), y=meantime, colour = method))  + ggtitle("Scaling with cell number.") #+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5E7))


ggplot(subset(df, ncol==1000)) + geom_point(aes(x = log10(ncol*nrow), y=meantime, colour = method))+ geom_line(aes(x = log10(ncol*nrow), y=meantime, colour = method)) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 3E7)) + ggtitle("Scaling with a wide matrix (1000 columns)")
ggplot(subset(df, nrow==1000)) + geom_point(aes(x = log10(ncol*nrow), y=meantime, colour = method))+ geom_line(aes(x = log10(ncol*nrow), y=meantime, colour = method)) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 3E7)) + ggtitle("Scaling with a tall matrix (1000 rows)")
```

The pink line is the case where we apply the vector over the columns with built in recycling.  Allocating a matrix with `matrix(vec, byrow=T)` scales the best of our options.

[image: Scaling with cell number]
[image: Scaling with cell number, small number of cells]

On the off chance that the matrix dimensions affected this here is scaling for a wide and a tall matrix.

[image: Wide matrix]
[image: Tall matrix]

Edit: It's worth noting that (as expected) the matrix allocation does not scale as well as vector recycling. The above plots are slightly misleading in that regard.

[image: Matrix vs recycling]